# What do you call the bottom part of a ballroom dress?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the bottom part of a female ballroom dress? I am referring to the part that extends out of the waist and may touch the floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the *skirt* of the dress, even though a separate garment covering the same area is also called a *skirt*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skirt)

> A skirt is the lower part of a dress/gown or a separate outer garment that covers a person from the waist downwards.